# Postfix Sends But Not receives mail

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix server that sends but doesn't receive mail, here's the config:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = cheesecakebb.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = cheese-ubuntu, localhost.localdomain, localhost cheesecakebb.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 100000
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost =
```

Error Log:

```
May  4 08:00:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/pickup[18114]: 80C2660649: uid=0 from=<root>
May  4 08:00:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[19043]: 80C2660649: message-id=<20140504120034.80C2660649@cheese-ubuntu>
May  4 08:00:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1418]: 80C2660649: from=<root@cheese-ubuntu>, size=462, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  4 08:00:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/local[19045]: 80C2660649: to=<root@cheese-ubuntu>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.09/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
May  4 08:00:34 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[1418]: 80C2660649: removed
May  8 17:30:15 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  8 17:33:40 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  8 17:33:40 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  8 17:35:12 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  8 17:35:45 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  9 02:38:41 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  9 02:38:41 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1205]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  9 10:24:39 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1228]: daemon started -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  9 10:28:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1228]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May  9 10:28:06 cheese-ubuntu postfix/master[1228]: reload -- version 2.9.6, configuration /etc/postfix
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/pickup[21395]: 55DA260665: uid=0 from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[25864]: 55DA260665: message-id=<1399701292.25794@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 55DA260665: from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>, size=576, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/error[25870]: 55DA260665: to=<loytd321@gmaiil.com>, relay=none, delay=0.13, delays=0.1/0/0/0.03, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (gmaiil.com)
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[25864]: 71F3B60694: message-id=<20140510055452.71F3B60694@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/bounce[25871]: 55DA260665: sender non-delivery notification: 71F3B60694
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 71F3B60694: from=<>, size=2243, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/local[25872]: 71F3B60694: to=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.05/0.05/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 55DA260665: removed
May 10 01:54:52 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 71F3B60694: removed
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/pickup[21395]: 3278E60665: uid=0 from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[25864]: 3278E60665: message-id=<1399701348.26042@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 3278E60665: from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>, size=576, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/error[25870]: 3278E60665: to=<loytd321@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.07/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (gmail.com)
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[25864]: 45C826070D: message-id=<20140510055548.45C826070D@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/bounce[25871]: 3278E60665: sender non-delivery notification: 45C826070D
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 45C826070D: from=<>, size=2239, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/local[25872]: 45C826070D: to=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.05/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 3278E60665: removed
May 10 01:55:48 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 45C826070D: removed
May 10 01:56:32 cheese-ubuntu postfix/pickup[21395]: 0934560665: uid=0 from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:56:32 cheese-ubuntu postfix/cleanup[25864]: 0934560665: message-id=<1399701391.26183@cheese-ubuntu>
May 10 01:56:32 cheese-ubuntu postfix/qmgr[2582]: 0934560665: from=<gage@cheese-ubuntu>, size=579, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Above is the error log, however, It doesn't make much sense to me as I am new to the postfix part of linux

Comment: Can you receive mail within the server itself between built-in accounts?

If so, have you registered an MX record with your domain name provider?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record

Comment: @Gerowen No. I cannot

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the log file for finding the exact cause of this error. Here's a simple checklist.

1. DNS resolution of the email hostname should give the correct ip address of the server.
2. The server should be listening on the right ports. Use telnet from a different machine to check firewall issues. 143 for non-ssl and 993 for ssl should be open.
3. Check in postfix log file, which in most cases can be found at `/var/log/mail.log`

Send a fresh email and check the last parts of log file to see what does the server do to your email.

Comment: There's not bounceback, it sends... it h=just doesn't show in inbox I guess?

Comment: Also, I edited the question to have the error log in it.